# Get the title of a given figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I have created a figure and have attached to it a title like this:

```
def func():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle("my title")
    return fig
```

Now I would like to retrieve the title I set in the function. Something like this:

```
fig.get_title()
```

It seems not to exist. Any idea besides returning the Text object that I can get from the fig.suptitle("w/e") function ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There seems to be no public API to access this. But with some cautions you could use the non-public / potentially instable members:

```
fig._suptitle.get_text()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can [get the title](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_title.html) through the axes:

```
fig.axes[0].get_title()
```

In case you have access to the axis itself, you can directly do:

```
ax.get_title()
```

The above is for getting the title associated with an axis e.g, set via `plt.title` or `ax.set_title`, i.e. the "usual" title.

---

But if you are looking for the title of the *figure* i.e. the `suptitle` in case it has been set (e.g., for a figure with many subplots), you can write

```
fig._suptitle.get_text()
```

Comment: it does not work for:

```fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,2)
fig.suptitle('lalala')
fig.axes[0].get_title()```

it returns empty string ''

Comment: @YardenCohen Yes, in case of multiple axes, things are a bit different because there are many possible titles! In your case, there could be 6 titles. But `suptitle` is above all of them, so to get that you can do: `fig._suptitle.get_text()`.

Comment: ...and the empty string it returns is the top left sub-figure's title, which is indeed not set and empty.

Comment: forgive me if I'm mistaken but isn't suptitle is ment for subplots?
since ax.title() is for specific plot so fig.suptitle() is for the entire figure

Comment: @YardenCohen Your second sentence seems to answer your question, no? `suptitle` is assocaited with the *figure* whereas the "usual" titles are associated with the *axes*.

Comment: I see now your edit,
Long story short, there is no public way of reading the figure suptitle..
(As the title of the question)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use `fig.texts` which returns a list of `matplotlib.text.Text` objects. Therefore, we can get the first element of the list, then use `get_text()` to get the actual title:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("my title")

text = fig.texts[0].get_text()
print(text)
# my title
```

Comment: Of course this only works if there haven't been any other texts added to the figure previously.