# matplotlib get figure number/string

Tags: matplotlib

When creating a figure in matplotlib by `plt.figure(num)`, `num` can be a number or a string.

I would like to obtain the string used for `num`.

As in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322986/how-do-you-get-the-current-figure-number-in-pythons-matplotlib) I can do 
`plt.figure(3); plt.gcf().number => 3`
but this does not work if `num` is a string.

How to get the string value?

(I am not asking about [`suptitle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392623/get-the-title-of-a-given-figure))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure label can be obtained via `fig.get_label()`

```
fig = plt.figure("ABCD")
print(fig.get_label())
```

If your figure does not have a label you can still get the number

```
if fig.get_label() == "":
    print(fig.number)
else:
    print(fig.get_label())
```